How to create square shaped nodes?
I'm new in sigma.js development, and I've been trying to create a custom shape node which is square, as per the docs, this is possible by using the "renderer".
Based on the docs, I need to instantiate the renderer with a declared type that uses the NodeCircleProgram and the name of the node type as key, refer to the code snippet below:
const renderer = new Sigma(graph, container, {
  allowInvalidContainer: true,
  defaultEdgeType: "straight",
  defaultNodeType: "square",
  nodeProgramClasses: {
    square: NodeCircleProgram,
    circle: NodeCircleProgram
  },
  edgeProgramClasses: {
    straight: EdgeArrowProgram,
    curved: EdgeCurvedArrowProgram
  }
})

Then this is how I'm rendering the nodes:
myNodes.forEach(value => {
  graph.addNode(value.key, {
    forceLabel: true,
    label: value.label,
    x: value.col,
    y: value.row,
    size: value.size,
    url: value.url,
    type: "square"
  })
})

Anyone that can point out what is the problem here? The nodes and edges are working fine with no error in the console logs, but the nodes is still circle.

It is normal that all your nodes are circle.
You are using the NodeCircleProgram for the square type in the settings.
The node square program has been implemented last week (August 2024) : https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/tree/main/packages/node-square

Install it with npm in your project : npm install @sigma/node-square
When you init sigma, you need to define it in the settings

import { NodeSquareProgram } from "@sigma/node-square";
...
const renderer = new Sigma(graph, container, {
  allowInvalidContainer: true,
  nodeProgramClasses: {
    square: NodeSquareProgram,
    circle: NodeCircleProgram
  },
  
})


Then on your nodes, you have to define the attribut type to square like you did

myNodes.forEach(value => {
  graph.addNode(value.key, {
    forceLabel: true,
    label: value.label,
    x: value.col,
    y: value.row,
    size: value.size,
    url: value.url,
    type: "square"
  })
})

